# Migration from Exchange 2003 to Google Apps

Tags: migration, g-suite

I cant get the migration to work from Exchange 2003. It uses IMAP for migration and I have enabled IMAP on every user in the Active Directory. It comes up with an error 'unable to authenticate the user'. The username and password are correct but it gives this error for all the users. Has anyone had this problem ?

Comment: What is "it" exactly? An email client, an application, etc.

Comment: Maybe too late, but you might be interested to know that Google has a new live migration process for Exchange 2003/2007 which doesn't rely on IMAP. http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2010/03/now-its-easy-switch-to-google-apps-from.html

Answer (score 1):

http://anchorite.org/blog/2007/08/18/exchange-2003-to-google-apps-migration-howto/

Don't know what your problem is, it could be the ports are wrong, your firewall is blocking it, your IMAP connector is off, your test account is locked out, g-standard-edition-restrictions, might need fully qualified name (user@domain.com).

You could ask google, those fellas are usually pretty switched on: http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=61369