# Migrating from Exchange to Google Apps for Business

Tags: exchange, g-suite, gmail

I am looking at migrating a client from their MS Exchange email server to Google Apps for Business email. They are a small firm with 5 email accounts, but they are very heavy email users and have mailfiles of 2-3GB each, with various attachments.

As their existing email server is a service, I cannot install any software on it. I think the only option is to use the google apps desktop migration tool.

Has anyone had an experience (successful or otherwise) in migrating mailfiles of this size to google apps? How long does it take and what happens if there is a network interruption (ie: can you restart?). Are there any problems with attachments?

Related Questions:

[Migration from Exchange 2003 to Google Apps](https://serverfault.com/questions/116278/migration-from-exchange-2003-to-google-apps)

[Migrating from Gmail to Google Apps](https://serverfault.com/questions/153373/migrating-from-gmail-to-google-apps?rq=1)

[How to migrate from Google Apps Mail](https://serverfault.com/questions/535095/how-to-migrate-from-google-apps-mail)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being a Google Apps reseller, this is actually our day-to-day work. 2-3GB mailboxes is quite an average, and we seldom deal with much larger than that.

Having your customer's current email being a service is no problem as long as you have an access to it. In case of a network disruptions, the Google migration tool is able to continue from the point it was last able to successfuly complete a transaction.

There are limitations for the migration process. Email messages failing to comply, will not get migrated.

For more information, see here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/179197?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the information. Any idea how long a 3GB mailfile would take to migrate, given a decent internet connection and PC?

Comment: It really is hard to tell:
Average ratio is 25 mail messages/minute. But, if a message contains large attachments, it could change that ratio.